# Make Action Link with Component ID in MVC3 RAZOR View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an code segment of view .cshtml page like :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Charts of Account", "Save")
```

Run mode i can see following HTML Code:

```
 <a href="/ChartsOfAccount/Save">Add Charts of Account</a>
```

But i want to following html code :

```
 <a id="lblAddNode" href="/ChartsOfAccount/Save">Add Charts of Account</a>
```

is it possible? If possible please explain with example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [overload of the ActionLink helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) which allows you to specify `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Add Charts of Account",    // linkText
    "Save",                     // actionName
    null,                       // routeValues
    new { id = "lblAddNode" }   // htmlAttributes
)
```